# Allocating more than what you need and freeing the extra space

Tags: c, malloc, free

I was wondering if it was possible to over allocate and free excess that you have allocated? I was thinking something along the lines of

```
/*
This is a pseudo program, just to show what I am talking about, there should be more
checks to prevent overflow.
*/
typedef struct {
  struct Node *neighbor
  int value
} Node;

...
Node create_tree(char* content, int size) {
  int mem_index = 0
  Node *last_node;
  // size > sizeof(Node)
  void base* = malloc(size);
  while( mem_index < size) {
    Node nptr* = (Node)(base + mem_index);
    if(last_node != NULL) nptr->neighbor = last_node;
    last_node = nptr;
    mem_index += sizeof(Node);
    nptr->value = (int)(base + mem_index)
    (nptr->value)* = get_some_content(content);
    mem_index += sizeof(int);   
  }
  free((base + mem_index));
}
```

Basically this program over allocates and begins casting the memory into structures and then writes to those structures. It points the pointers within the structure to further points in the memory. It then writes another structure past all of that unit it is done with writing. I am wondering if this is possible, and if it is, is it good practice? I have heard under allocating is an issue, and I am not a fan of allocating every time I want to create a new structure if I am going to be creating them dynamically.

Comment: "*I am not a fan of allocating every time I want to create a new structure*". That is generally a better way than what you have. Unless you need to very carefully manage the memory, such as a specialised embedded system, it is arguably better just to let the standard library allocator manage all that. It will make your code much simpler, easier to understand and less error prone.

Comment: But no, you cannot `free` just part of the memory. You need to allocate a new smaller block, copy all the data from the larger block to the smaller one and then `free` the larger one. Fortunately there is a standard function that can do that for you - `realloc`.

Comment: Note: `void base* = malloc(size); ... base + mem_index` is not portable code.  With standard C, cannot add to a `void *`.

Comment: You can only pass an address to `free()` that was obtained from `malloc()` etc. The exact address, not somewhere within the allocation.

Comment: The `int` type is not the most suitable to keep track of relative memory offsets. The `ptrdiff_t` seems more suitable. Also be very aware of memory alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use realloc to shrink the memory block to the desired size:

```
base2 = realloc(base, mem_index);
```

If the call is successful, then the memory after `base + mem_index` will be freed.

BTW. Using pointer of type `void*` for arithmetic is GCC extension. You should use `char*`.

Note that returned `base2` may not be same as the original `base`. You update all existing references to base with base2.

Comment: Not strictly true. The entire block might be freed, and another smaller block allocated in another part of memory.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, I've added an appropriate note at the end.